# Black login screen after Mojave update – temporarily fixed with dummy user and blind logout

Tags: display, mojave, user-account, login

I currently experience a crazy macOS bug.

After updating from 10.12.6 over 10.13.6 to 10.14.6 my Mac Pro 5,1 boots to a black login screen. VoiceOver tells me that the login is there, but everything is black. No cursor. No nothing. Through a huge portion of serendipity I found this temporary fix:

1. Using safe-mode I created a dummy user without password and set this user to auto-login (so it boots right through)
2. Boot › Auto-login › then I blindly logout using VoiceOver
3. And tadaaa: As soon as the logout is done the login screen comes up and I can login to my normal user. Mojave then behaves just as expected. No further problems so far.

I have no idea how to fix this permanently. What could a logout trigger that would suddenly make the screen appear? Or asked the other way: What would make the screen go black after 3/4 of the boot that a logout fixes? Hints greatly appreciated.